# HTML5 Canvas ShadowBlur and Flip Horizontal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas

I have a transparent GIF image and I am trying to replicate the IE glow filter using the HTML5 Canvas (don't ask).  I can do it by drawing the exact same image "underneath" the image that is on top with a shadowBlur filter.

The problem is that the image sometimes has to be flipped horizontally, and the shadowBlur doesn't fire if the image is flipped (still invisible under the img tag as it's the exact same dimensions).

Previous code:

```
if (flipped)
  AddFilter('progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(mirror=1,rotation=0)');
AddFilter('progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Glow(Color=" + glowColor + ",Strength=" + glowRank + ")"');
```

HTML5 Canvas code:

```
context.shadowBlur = glowRank * 2;  // Canvas not as strong
context.shadowColor = glowColor;

if (flipped) {
  context.translate(img[0].width, 0);
  context.scale(-1, 1);
}

context.drawImage(img[0], img.position().left - 8, img.position().top - 8, img[0].width, img[0].height);
```

So, basically, we can flip the image or shadowBlur it, but not both.  And this is in all browsers.  Any way to do both?  Pre-render the flipped image somehow and use that?

(And there are 1000s of images, so we can't flip them all ahead of time.  It has to be done on the fly.)

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing is making a tiny canvas for each image instead of 1 large one that was the whole playfield.  I then positioned/flipped the tiny canvases instead.